# How to change video in YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, video

On my YouTube channel it shows the latest video that I uploaded.

Can I change it to a different video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the featured video on your channel page, follow the steps below:

- Sign in and go to your channel page.
- On your channel page select the 'Videos and Playlists' tab.
- Select the video you'd like to feature from the "Featured video" dropdown or select "Use the most recent video from my featured set."
- Click the Save Changes button.

http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97392

Hope this helps.